# Split file into the List

Tags: file, groovy

I have txt file for example:

```
useless text
-- modelName
model parameters
model parameters

-- modelName
model parameters
model parameters

e.t.c
```

I need to split this file into List where the elements of the list is  model with model parametrs.
My algoritm for this

```
File(FILEPATH).eachLine { line ->
            if (line =regExpForModelName) {
              while(line!=regExpForModelName)
                model.add(line)
            }
        }
```

`while(line!=regExpForModelName)` is clearly wrong

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problems did you have?

Comment: Oh, forgot put my code.
Im stuck in reading model parametrs.
My idieas was 
` File(FILEPATH).eachLine { line ->
            if (line =regExpForModelName) {
            while(line.next()!=regExpForModelName)
                Model.add(line)
            }
        } `
But ofc code "while(line.next()!=regExpForModelName)" not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a simple state machine like so:

```
enum State {
    SCANNING, PARSING
}

def parseFile(String filename) {
    def key = null
    def result = []
    def mode = State.SCANNING
    new File(filename).eachLine { line ->
        switch(mode) {
            case State.SCANNING:
                if(line.startsWith('--')) {
                    key = (line - '--').trim()
                    result << [name:key, lines:[]]
                    mode = State.PARSING
                }
                break
            case State.PARSING:
                if(line.size() == 0) {
                    mode = State.SCANNING
                }
                else {
                    result[-1].lines << line
                }
        }
        result
    }
}

def results = parseFile('/tmp/file.txt')

results.each {
    println it
}
```

So it starts off SCANNING, and then when it finds a header item, it adds a new element to the list and switches to PARSING

Then it keeps PARSING (and adding lines to the list) until it hits an empty line, when it switches back into a SCANNING state

Comment: Oh, thanks.
I thought mb groovy has some magic moves for this parsing.

Comment: Not really...  You could probably do something daring and shorter, but you'll be glad when you come back to this and have to work out what it does ;-)